# What to do with seized / split chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate, brownies

My kids love making brownies, but every now and then the water gets into the bowl while they are melting the chocolate. The chocolate then seizes or splits, and you have a sodden mess.

Can this chocolate be used for anything?

At the moment, it just goes in the bin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're not talking about very much water getting into the bowl, then these techniques should help.

1. Remove the bowl of chocolate from the heat source.
2. For every ounce of chocolate, add one tablespoon of one of these:   warm water, melted butter, vegetable oil, hot milk/cream.
3. Stir or whisk until smooth. Add a bit more liquid if needed.
4. Use the repaired chocolate for sauce, frosting, or a batter (like for your brownies!). It won't work well for coating candy.

You may also want to check out [this discussion](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/melting-chocolate-without-it-getting-wet) on how to melt chocolate without getting it wet.

Answer (score 6):

If it was just a few drops of water, keep mixing for two or three minutes while keeping the chocolate warm.  The water will evaporate and the chocolate will remix. If it is more water, use it as @JustRightMenus suggested.

Answer (score 4):

At the very least, put it in a sauce pot with some milk for killer milk chocolate. Or:

Eat it right out of the bowl.

Put it inside a rolled up puffed pastry/pie dough for a homemade strudel/thingy.

Mix with eggs, flour, oil, and milk for chocolate cake.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread looking for a solution to the sample problem... Over cooked my whitenchocolatE. From advice of the entry regarding adding water and oil, I mixed In peanut butter. The mixture softened up and coated some crackers quite well!  It was for eating, not for selling so I can't say how it turned out for presentation, but it was delish.  Thanks for the hints folks.

Answer (score 1):

My ganache sauce split (chocolate and cream) as I overheated it. I put it into my Vitamix and blended until smooth again.

It was PERFECT again!!!!! Sacher tort looked amazing with shiny glaze.

Answer (score 1):

#### Homemade Cadbury Flakes

[Cadbury Flakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flake_(chocolate_bar)) are a chocolate bar that is made from a thin layer of seized chocolate curled and twisted up into a bar shape. This is why they burn rather than melt, and crumble in your mouth.

Here is a video by a food scientist discussing the method by which she reverse engineered this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdaKrT9x1Zc&t=902s

Answer (score 1):

A tiny small amount of thick coconut oil works perfect.  Stick in microwave for 15 seconds at a time mixing it thouroghly each time till you get the desired meltyness.  Use for whatever.