# How can I avoid seizing chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, tempering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you melt chocolate without it getting wet?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/how-can-you-melt-chocolate-without-it-getting-wet)

When tempering chocolate over a water bath, how can I avoid getting any droplets of water into the chocolate?  These water droplets will cause the chocolate to seize!

Comment: Where are the water droplets dripping from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had an issue with this, I guess if the steam was condensating above the pot or on your tools it could drip in, in that case an extractor fan might help. Other than that just be careful:

- don't to have the water boiling to high, creating too much steam, it only needs to be simmering
- don't use too much water, it needs to more than cover the bottom of the pot but doesn't need to come up to the bowl with the chocolate in
- take it slowly

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 teaspoon of potato starch (or maizena).

Comment: How exactly does this help?